# Bonobo.Git.Server early error

Tags: iis, bonobo

I'm trying to install **Bonobo.Git.Server** on my Windows 2008 R2 server (under IIS 7.0). I followed step by step the installation procedure ([bonobo install](https://bonobogitserver.com/install/)) but when I try to access the application URL I got the following error:
[image: Error page]
What's up?

Answer (score 0):

Well I forgot to install .NET Framework 4.6 (that was one of the prerequisites) now it works.